# Is there a way to identify issues during app publication that don't occur locally?

Tags: office365, office-js, word-addins

I am trying to submit a new Word add-in to the app store. Microsoft encounters a problem while testing the application (trying to switch languages within the app; the app loads a language file from a publically accessible file, from a domain that has been added to the list of domains in the .xml file).

Microsoft added a video showing nothing happening when clicking the language button but I am not able to reproduce this issue, nor am I able to contact Microsoft for more information about this issue.

The primary issue here is an inability to identify the source of this problem and/or similar issues during the publication process, rather than the problem we're currently having regarding switching languages.

Answer (score 0):

The certification team can be communicated with through the certification notes field when resubmitting the add-in.